# How do I disable the "main redeclared" check in golint on Atom's go-plus package?

Tags: go, atom-editor

I've just started learning go and am using Atom with the go-plus package for coding. As such, all my code resides in one folder with each file having its own func main.

Each time I save the code, the linter runs and gives the error `main redeclared in this block`. I understand that when I start using go in an actual project, I need to have only one main per folder, but right now, that isn't necessary. Having multiple folders with only one file in each is  quite cumbersome.

Is there any way I can turn off the "main redeclared" option in the linter?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, as you, I just started to learn Go language with Atom but after some research a found this link that could solve our problem.

https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/go-colorful/issues/5

The solution proposed is to add the underscore character `"_"` to your file name. In this way you will have a project folder structured like this:

> Go workplace
>
> 1. _example1.go
> 2. example2.go

and Atom does not show error message `main redeclared in this block`, but to run by teminal the `_example1.go` you must delete the `"_"` and add it to `example2.go`, in this way you can run `example1.go`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using terminal for running your one-file go programs, you can work with that error. Running `go run example1.go` will run your code without any error. Running `go run example2.go` will also run your other files without errors.

Answer (score 1):

More recently (2019), [**`github.com/mgechev/revive`**](https://github.com/mgechev/revive) ([initiated in July 2017](https://github.com/mgechev/revive/commit/891f525abcb6d08ff6e491dbeec9f9d3f997b151)) is a good alternative:

- faster
- Allows to enable or disable rules using a configuration file.
- Provides functionality for disabling a specific rule or the entire linter for a file or a range of lines. (only for generated files.)
- *Everyone can extend it easily with custom rules or formatters.*

And it has an [Atom plugin](https://github.com/morphy2k/linter-revive).

The last point would let you develop a custom rule that analyse and shows nothing if multiple `main()` are detected within a folder.